# How to add many selections to one variable in tcl

Tags: tcl

after doing some other things in my script I end up with a series of variables set in tcl ($sel1, $sel2, $sel3, ...) and I need to add them to the following line:

```
set all [::TopoTools::selections2mol "$box $sel1 $sel2 $sel3 $sel4"]
```

Now, if I only had four this would be fine by hand, but in the final version I will have hundreds which is untenable to do by hand. I'm sure the answer is some kind of loop, but I've been giving it some thought now and I can't quite figure it out. If I had, say, $sel1, $sel2, all the way to a given number, how would I add them to that line in the format shown at any amount that I want, with the $box at the beginning as shown? Thanks very much for your help.

It may or may not be relevant, but I define the variables in a loop as follows:

```
set sel$i [atomselect $id all]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the software you are using, but it should be possible to fix this without too much hassle.

If you put this inside the loop instead:

```
set sell$i [atomselect $id all]
append valueStr " " [set sell$i]
```

(or perhaps this, even if it is little C:)

```
append valueStr " " [set sell$i [atomselect $id all]]
```

you will get the string that `" $sel1 $sel2 $sel3 $sel4"` is substituted into (remember to put `$box` in as well).

With Tcl 8.5 or later,  you can do

```
dict set values $i [atomselect $id all]
```

inside the loop, which gives you a dictionary structure containing all values, and then create the sequence of values with:

```
set all [::Topotools::selections2mol [concat $box [dict values $values]]]
```

Depending on the output and input formats of `atomselect` and `selections2mol`, the latter might not actually work without a little fine-tuning, but it should be worth a try.

In the latter case, you aren't getting the variables, but each value is available as

```
dict get $values $i
```

You can do this with an array also:

```
set values($i) [atomselect $id all]
```

but then you need to sort the keys before collecting the values, like this

```
set valueStr [list $box]
foreach key [lsort -integer [array names values]] {
    append valueStr " " $values($key)
}
```

Documentation:
[append](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/append.htm),
[array](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/array.htm),
[concat](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/concat.htm),
[dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm),
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm),
[lsort](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsort.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)